# Getting warning while using struts.xml file.

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2.0. When i am writting a program, in struts.xml file getting warning "**the file cannot be validated as there was a connection problem** " at the line:-" !DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd" "

When i am executing the application first page is loaded but after submitting,the next page is not loaded and showing error like: "**The requested resource (/TestProject/login) is not available**."

I am using struts2.0,Tomcat6.0, and including jar files are :

1. commons-logging-1.1
2. freemarker-2.3.8
3. ognl-2.6.11
4. struts2-core-2.0.6
5. xwork-2.0.1

plz help me why this error is coming either due to warning or some other reason.

Comment: Check is there any unwanted character or space before !Doctype

Comment: Try the below lines, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">`  see to that no space before <?xml

Comment: Turn devMode on, turn up logging to DEBUG, and check your console. You need to provide more information regarding the action configuration of the action you're submitting to, how you're accessing the first page (through an action, or straight to a JSP?), and so on. That's also a *very* early version of S2, and really shouldn't be used. I don't remember that far back, but you may also need Commons IO and Commons fileupload--you should really be using Maven to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error may be because your project is not able to find tld's.

-Check your sturts-core.jar contains struts-2.0.dtd
-Your struts.xml starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

Second error is because when you are deploying your application and struts.xml is not getting deployed, seems you are using eclipse and your struts.xml is in resources folder.

Ensure that your resources folder is added in the src directories,

```
Project - > Build Path - > Configure Build Path - > Source (If resources is not present here click on Add Folder and select Resources.
```

If you are just starting with Struts, please upgrade to latest version which is [Struts2.3](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/)

Comment: TLDs?! I don't think we know why the page isn't available; there's not enough information to go on.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I have encoutered similar issue while starting with Struts2, added a resource folder in eclipse but didnt mark it in source folder, since index page is defined in web.xml didnt had any issue, but any action there after resulted in the same error.

Comment: thnx mprabhat. ur suggestion help me a lot.